# Publishing or uploading failed. Error message: "The response is not a valid JSON response"

Tags: wordpress

Today I got an issue in WordPress. When I try to create a new page and uploading a new image in the WordPress admin section, I try to find out the solution, but I didn't get it... So after sanding an hour I got a solution...

#### Error

> "Publishing failed. Error message: The response is not a valid JSON response."

Comment: What do you mean by *"after sanding an hour"*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right now, you can use the *[Classic Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/)* plugin for fixing this issue.

The answer for the error is the editor I didn't know, but there is a new editor issue. If you are getting the same issue, then please use the below plugin. For fixing these issues, I'm doing R&D on this issue. If I get an exit solution, then will I make an update soon...

Comment: It doesn't solves the problem for real. 
If you run in this problem, just open the Inspect Window in your browser and go to Network tab. If you see a 404 when you try to publish your page, you should consider @sgaith answer here below. It can be a `.htaccess` configuration problem and/or a `mod_rewrite` configuration problem.

Comment: I needed to use the "post name" permalink, but none of the other solutions worked for me. I did end up changing the permissions of my `.htaccess` before this, so maybe that has something to do with it but I'm not sure. Using the classic editor is the only approach that worked for me.

Answer (score 27):

Go to settings>permalinks. Select "Post name" and save.

Try updating your posts/pages. If it doesnot work, try selecting another option in the settings>permalinks.

Comment: Also, check the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem on a local dev environment and found the issue was due to rewrite permissions. Make sure your .htaccess file has the proper permission.

```
sudo chmod 755 .htaccess
```

After permissions are set, save your permalink settings. If the problem still exists, make sure mod_rewrite is enabled. The following will work for apache2 on Ubuntu.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl apache2 restart
```

If still not working, your apache config is probably too strict. The following should do the trick for apache2 on Ubuntu. Edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and look for the root directory block. It's normally the one with /var/www like below. You will probably see AllowOverride None. Just change it to All like below for your local, but you probably want to do some research and be more secure on a production server.

> `<Directory /var/www/>`
>           `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`
>           `AllowOverride All`
>           `Require all granted`
>   `</Directory>`

After the change is made do another restart on apache and all should be good.

```
sudo systemctl apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 7):

Changing the permalink settings as mentioned previously fixed the problem for me. If you keep "Post name" as the permalink setting, then the .htaccess file needs to be writable by wordpress.

Alternatively the below can be pasted at the bottom of .htaccess file. Mod_rewrite changes are executed from the bottom of the file first.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you have a **security issue** with mixed content (HTTP and https URLs).
Step-1 
1.  1. Check your Wordpress URL. Go to Settings -> permalink then click plain and save a page. then remove error

Step-2

1. Check your Wordpress URL. Go to Settings -> General
2. Change Wordpress Adress and Site Adress to **https://**

This solved the problem for me

Comment: Perfect! This was the issue with mine. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 5):

**Go to** /etc/nginx/sites-available/
open default file --> **sudo vi default** or **sudo nano default**

Add Below line to the location:

Add the comment :
**#try_files $uri $uri/ =404;**

Add this line : ***try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;***

**See the screenshot below described with red line :**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to **Settings** > **Permalinks**. Select the permalink structure to Post name and save. Now try saving your post/page.

Here I have shared the screen-shot for your reference.

[image]

The problem should have been resolved.

Once your issue is resolved then you can select an old option in Permalinks if you want.

**Note: If you have already selected Post Name then you need to select other option for reset permalink.**

Answer (score 1):

I just installed classic editor plugin and it sorted out the “The response is not a valid JSON response” problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same "not a valid JSON response" error when trying to publish my content. WordPress seems to do a JSON post when publishing a new post/page so I checked the network tab in my Developer Tools. If you check the "response" tab for this JSON call you might see some more details about this invalid JSON response.

In my case (yours might be different) some deprecated debug message was outputted before the actual JSON data and messed up the response. After fixing the deprecated message publishing worked again.

```html
<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
{__NORMAL_JSON_DATA_HERE__}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, here there are two server blocks, first one is running on port 80.
for second server block there is a port 443 where you should implement the below code.

server{ 
#ssl configuration 
location / { 
# First attempt to serve request as file, then 
# as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404. 
# try_files $uri $uri/ =404; // comment this block 
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args; 
} 
} 
Now exit and restart nginx server. 
[image]
~$ sudo service nginx restart

you are done. enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

In My case, it was a Firewall issue. A ModSecurity firewall rule was triggered for the website. I contacted the hosting provider (NameCheap), they identified the issue and then whitelisted the triggered rule on the server. Then the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this still has not been fixed.

A workaround that worked for me (posting in case it works for someone else too) - in my case I was using an HTML block which was causing the issue. What I did was to add a Paragraph block > Edit as HTML. It resolved the issue for now. It's a shame that WP didn't look into it yet, seems like it's been happening for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and the cause in my case was a shortcode used in the page and the function that defined the shortcode was using 'echo' to output the data rather than using 'return'

Answer (score 0):

I'd been getting the same error message when adding and/or updating pages, in addition to various other random errors.  I was getting the errors on both my local development server and my webhost.  When changing to one of the default themes (e.g. twenty nineteen), the errors would go away.  For me, the problem turned out to be in my page template files.  I'd noticed that when choosing a template for a newly created page, I'd have multiple choices with the same name.

I have several page template files (e.g. about-page.php, contact-page.php, services-page.php, etc.).  When creating these files, since most of these pages were similar, I would just copy/paste from an existing file to make a new xxxx-page.php file. However, in some of those copied files (not all), I'd forgotten to modify the 'Template Name' (at the top of the file).

After I'd gone through and made sure all of my template files had unique names, the JSON error went away.  All of my other errors disappeared as well.  I'm using Wordpress 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was **.htaccess** related. I got the hint from LucasBr's comment about a ".htaccess configuration problem". Since I had copied the site to my local dev environment. I needed to update the custom mod_rewrite settings to match my setup.

The important lines were:

```
RewriteBase /
```

and

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

They had previously been set to access a sub-directory site.

Answer (score 0):

I have some echo in some of my custom plugins, so this was also causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the persisting issues. Before I could find the solution, I replaced PHP 8, as this was custom PHP Installation.

But nothing worked.

The solution was found during Drupal Installation.

1. Enable Opcache(only for Drupal though)
2. Allow Mod rewrite, Allow all(in my `httpd.ini` file there were three occurrences of Mod Rewrite,

And they were changed to `None` to `All` again `none` `all` this was small letter, and final one `None` to `All`

Restart httpd with `httpd -k restart` (CMD as Administrator)

This resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same kind of problem for a different reason with one of my client and never saw it as a potential solution.

If you enabled a W.A.F (like cloudflare or similar), one of the side effects can be this error, so be sure to disable to disable you waf if none of the other solutions are working.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [mod security 3](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity) with Wordpress, you might get this message:

**Publishing failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.**

To remove it, you would need to add this rule to your exclusions file called

```
REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS
```

as follows:

```
# Remove Publishing failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "example.com" \
     "id:1025,\
     phase:2,\
     pass,\
     nolog,\
     chain"
     SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /wp-json/wp/v2" \
         " ctl:ruleRemoveById=933210,ctl:ruleRemoveById=949110"
```

You might need to change the rule id and change example.com to your domain name. After that, do this:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

if no problems were detected, restart nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, also in my case, I couldn't download and uninstall plugins. and in the page source there were:
`<head> </head>` tag before `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your case it could be just whitespace. the problem was in the function.php file, at the end of the file I had php closing tag `?>`. after removing it everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

This is a permalinks error.

Do these steps to fix it (depending upon the cause in your scenario) as explained here: https://wordpress786.com/updating-failed-error-message-the-response-is-not-a-valid-json-response/ :

1. go to `settings > permalinks` and save them once again
2. if you're on **nginx**, go to site nginx **conf** file and make sure that it contains the rules for wordpress permalinks (usual nginx configurationn for wordpress, ask me if confused)
3. restart nginx if you make any edits to conf file

Answer (score -1):

If you face issue on image upload follow this: https://navinrao.com/the-response-is-not-a-valid-json-response/

> I was getting this issue while updating normal text too. 
>   The issue I face was due to having **javascript:void(0)** keyword inside my link () .
>
> Please be sure if your content has keyword containing javascript
>   before updating.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" title="Linkedin" class="social-color-3"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

> After I remove **javascript:void(0)** ; it works fine.
>   Have a nice time :)

Answer (score -1):

Try removing any redirects to the WordPress site including subdomains.