# Wordpress "Save Draft" fails: "the response is not a valid JSON response"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this error every time I try to save my draft or publish or many other operations (and on all the news):

```
Updating failed. Error message: The response is not a valid JSON response.
```

[image: Wordpress json not valid]

Request:

```
{"id":488,"content":"<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>Try </p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->","title":"Try"}
```

Response extract, looking at network tab (for some bizarre reason it includes html in addition to json):

```
<span class="posted-on">Posted on
...
</span>{"id":488,"date":"2020-05-08T22:57:44","date_gmt":"2020-05-08T21:57:44","guid":{"rendered":
...
```

The solution used for other questions is to use the old `Classic Editor` but i prefear the new one:
[Publishing or uploading failed. Error message: "The response is not a valid JSON response"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009827/publishing-or-uploading-failed-error-message-the-response-is-not-a-valid-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this error was stupid. The problem was that when wordpress sent a JSON request, the answer was not in JSON format. There was an `echo` instead of `return` in one of my theme functions, under template-tags.php.

This caused each json to take that html out with it.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_posted_on' ) ) {
    function my_posted_on() {
        $time_string = '';
        // ...
        $posted_on   = apply_filters(
            'my_posted_on', sprintf(
                '<span class="posted-on">...</span>',
                esc_html_x( 'Posted on', 'post date', 'theme' ),
                esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                apply_filters( 'my_posted_on_time', $time_string )
            )
        );
        $byline      = apply_filters(
            'my_posted_by', sprintf(
                '...'
            )
        );
        echo $posted_on . $byline;
    }
}
```

I replaced `echo` with `return` and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Update Your permalink.
If not Fixed Disable the Block editor and switch back to Classic editor.

Answer (score 0):

@aepifano is right! I got this error when I was trying to save a post:

```
Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.
```

I was testing a plugin that had this code:

```
function plugin_b_shortcode()
{
    $latest = '';
    $content = '';

    if(function_exists('plguin_a_latest_post'))
    {
        $latest = plguin_a_latest_post();
    }

    if(is_array($latest) && !empty($latest))
    {
        echo "<pre>";print_r($latest);echo "</pre>";

        $newdate = $latest['post_date'];
        $newdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($newdate.' -7 hours '));
        $newdate = date("D M j G:i:s T Y",strtotime($newdate));

        $content .= '<div style="padding:22px; border:solid 1px #000; background-color:#CCC;">';
            $content .= '<h1>Latest Post</h1>';
            $content .= '<h2><a href="'.get_permalink($latest['ID']).'">'.$latest['post_title'].'</a></h2>';
            $content .= '<p>Date: '.$newdate.'</p>';
        $content .= '</div>';
    }

    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('plugin_a_latest','plugin_b_shortcode');
```

When I changed `echo` to `return` I was able to update the post BUT I didn't have the outcome I wanted after I changed `echo` to `return`. If there is any other solution please let us know about it.